# Restructure an array of objects in JS so key and value pairs match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects like this

```
[ 
  {name: 'Donegal', code: 'DL'}, 
  {name: 'Dublin', code: 'DUB'}, 
  {name: 'Meath', code: 'MH'}
]
```

How do I restructure it so it looks like this

```
[ 
  {Donegal: 'Donegal'}, 
  {Dublin: 'Dublin'}, 
  {Meath: 'Meath'}
]
```

**** EDIT ****

Apologies, but after receiving feedback, I looked at my question again and realized that I wrote the desired object incorrectly, apologies for that.  Regardless, the question has been answered (Thank you everyone for your comments and answers).  For the record, here is the desired output

```
[ 
  {
    Donegal: 'Donegal', 
    Dublin: 'Dublin', 
    Meath: 'Meath'
  }
]
```

Comment: "_I have a JSON with content like this_" - That has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Do you really want an array of separate objects all containing a single property? A single object having all the properties would probably be more useful.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have in your question is an array of objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Also, I'm with @Ivar -- having different properties in each object is awkward to use.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a beginner and I have updated the question

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need this specific type of object? Because `yourlist.map(e => e.name)` gets you an array of the values you need, after which you can do whatever you want with them. Turning them into same-stringed key:value pairs adds nothing on top of just having the bare list of those values.

Comment: Why would you want *that* as output? So you want little objects which each have a different property name, and their values are .... wait for it ... the *same* as the key??

Comment: It's for translation.  The string is the english translation of the key

Comment: I cannot imagine a translation tool that requires that kind of input. Why not *one* object?

Comment: `const dst = src.map(x => ({[x.name]: x.name}));` is one way to do it.

Comment: FWIW, this is what I think you _actually_ want: A single object that maps words to their translation, but in this case happens to be an identity mapping. e.g. EN->EN. `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(src).map(([, { name }]) => [name, name]));`

Comment: Oh my god.... you're actually right.  I wrote the question down wrong.  I'm a bloody fool. Thank you.  Ugh I'm so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you are targeting looks wrong: having an array with little objects that have one dynamic property, kills any benefit you would have from using object keys.

Instead go for *one* object (not an array):

```js
let input = [ 
  {name: 'Donegal', code: 'DL'}, 
  {name: 'Dublin', code: 'DUB'}, 
  {name: 'Meath', code: 'MH'}
];

let output = Object.fromEntries(
    input.map(({name}) => [name, name])
);

console.log(output);
```